# Can't instantiate COM interop interface in a Windows Runtime component

Tags: windows-8, com-interop, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5

I'm working on a Windows Runtime component, written in C#, to wrap some COM interfaces that don't have Windows Runtime equivalents, following [this MSDN example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Modern-Win32COM-mobile-8f762ad8) which uses the interop interfaces provided by mbnapi.tlb. When I try to instantiate my IMbnInterfaceManager member in the wrapper class's constructor, like so:

```
m_InterfaceManager = (IMbnInterfaceManager)new MbnInterfaceManager();
```

it throws a System.InvalidCastException due to E_NOINTERFACE (No such interface supported).

However, if I build my wrapper as a Class Library instead of a WinMD component, it works fine, with no other changes.

I'd much rather build this as a Windows Runtime component, so as not to limit the usefulness of the library. (At least one of the projects this is intended for is being written in Javascript/HTML.) Am I doing something wrong, or is what I'm trying to do not possible?

EDIT: Turns out it's a bug in the .NET 4.5 RC. Leaving this question here in case anybody else runs into this issue, and I'll post a workaround if I find one. Supposedly it'll be fixed by RTM.

Comment: Threading is the usual reason for mysterious E_NOINTERFACE errors.

Comment: That's the impression I got from trying to research this issue on my own - but the execution path _seems_ identical whether it's built as a Windows Runtime component or a class library. In both cases, it's the main UI thread that's trying to instantiate the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a bug in the .NET 4.5 RC, and purportedly will be fixed by RTM. The current workaround is to edit the .csproj file and set EmbedInteropTypes to False for the reference to the tlb/dll. This can cause the App Store Certification Test to fail, so be sure to set it back to True once the .NET bug is fixed.